# Linq Select and SelectMany performing joins

Tags: c#, linq

> C# 6.0 in a Nutshell by Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari (O’Reilly).
>
> Copyright 2016 Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari, 978-1-491-92706-9.

Exposes, in chapter 9, on Linq Operators. For each operation, such as filtering, projecting, joining, etc, it lists the extension methods available in System.Linq to perform the operation in question.

At page 394, it deals with projecting:

> **Projecting** (Input: `IEnumerable<TSource>` → Output: `IEnumerable<TResult>`)
>
> Transforms each element with a lambda function. SelectMany flattens
>   nested sequences; `Select` **and** `SelectMany` perform inner joins, left
>   outer joins, cross joins, and non-equi joins with LINQ to SQL and EF:
>
> **Linq API**: Select, SelectMany

Intuitively, its much easier to see how `SelectMany` is equivalent to joining in relational databases, but what about `Select` alone ? I'm not sure I see how Select alone can do any sort of joining.

Could it be that the only case where `Select` does something equivalent to a join is like

```
IEnumerable<TInput> input = ...

input.Select(new [SomeType] { a = input.a + c, b = input.a + d };
```

It could be said then that this `Projection` is implicitly defining a relation between type `TInput` and `SomeType`, and thus representing a join ? Am I right ?

Comment: No is is not like joining.  Select many is when you have a multi-dimensional array and the select many takes an inner array and moves all items to the next higher dimension of the multi-dimensional array.  So if you have a two dimensional table a select many will take all the rows of the table and make them into a single one dimensional array.

Comment: @jdweng: thanskf for your input, but you just explained what technically a SelectMany does. Which I knew. Given that the author relates Select and SelectMany with joining, I am trying to explain how these operators relate to performing joining. As I mentioned, SelectMany is more intuitive, since the relation between Order and Purchase tables may be translated into a class Order having a list of Purchases. So in a list of Orders, doing a SelectMany on Purchases will do what you describe - we all agree - but the point of the question is to analyse where/how these operations perform a join

Comment: (cont.) and in this example it is easy to see how/where. Select alone is not that intuitive.

Comment: @jdweng: stating "no is not like joining" implies you disagree with the author.

Answer (score 3):

A Simple example:

```
context.Students.where(x=> x.StudentID == 1).Select(x=> x.Department).FirstOrDefault();
```

is Equivelant to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 D.* FROM Student S 
INNER JOIN Department D
ON S.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
WHERE S.StudentID = 1
```

Basically using `Select` in combination with navigation properties may result in a `JOIN` at some point. In the above Linq Query you're selecting the Department for that Student with `ID == 1`.

I'm not 100 % sure if that provider would generate an `INNER` or `LEFT` join, but the point is that a JOIN operation is resulted from a `Select` method.

Comment: Revisiting this answer, I think in the example above, it is not the Select that does a JOIN, it is the Navigation Property. In other words, it is the way the Students Entity was designed, it will always perform a join behind the scenes, regardless of using LINQ's Select. For that matter, `context.Students.where(x=> x.StudentID == 1)` alone will do the same `INNER JOIN Department D
ON S.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID`